# Aurelia CLI viewport does not render

Tags: aurelia

I created a new aurelia project for **typescript** following the docs here
https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager.
The installed version of the CLI is aurelia-cli v1.0.0-beta.13. I followed all the steps including changing the samples to TS as required. I did download the additional assets required and renamed the files per the docs. When I type "au run" or "au run --watch", the site compiles without error.

The viewport never renders. It is completely blank. However, the title does render.
If I look at the source of the page, this is what I see exactly as formatted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aurelia Navigation Skeleton</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <!-- imported CSS are concatenated and added automatically -->
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/runtime~app.89f02086e8de1923ee27.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~7e79ec10.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~556c66f2.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~72fdf3f2.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~50e8d500.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~5ea1390f.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~ecff2e3d.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~02227409.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~7274e1de.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~1dd9cae8.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~db300d2f.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~b58f7129.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~ec8c427e.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~95a414bc.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~de47f514.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors~5196d596.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/app~d0ae3f07.89f02086e8de1923ee27.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Node Version is v10.15.2

NPM is 6.8.0

Windows version 7

Typescript version is 3.3.3333

How do I get chrome, firefox, or IE11 to render something?

Comment: I tried this and its' rendering hello word fine for me. Can you check if you got any erros?

Comment: Did not get any errors. I think, however, I did find a solution. Peer Dependancies needed to be installed for bootstrap, font-awesome, aurelia-tools. Did that, solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I installed bootstrap, there were a number of dependencies required to be loaded as well.

```
npm WARN acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aurelia-tools@2.0.0 requires a peer of babel-eslint@^7.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN aurelia-tools@2.0.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I would have thought when the CLI was installed that aurelia-tools would have installed the eslint and babel-eslint packages but, that's a different discussion.

Comment: If you need any further help, just shoot me a msg on discoruse / gitter. Glad you resolved it